# Creating a new columns from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset which is in longformat in which Measurements (Time) are nested in Networkpartners (NP) which are nested in Persons (ID), here is an example of what it looks like (the real dataset has over thousands of rows):

```
ID  NP  Time Outcome
1   11  1    4
1   11  2    3
1   11  3    NA
1   12  1    2
1   12  2    3
1   12  3    3
2   21  1    2
2   21  2    NA
2   21  3    NA
2   22  1    4
2   22  2    4
2   22  3    4
```

Now I would like to create 3 new variables:

a) The Number of Networkpartners (who have no NA in the outcome at this measurement) a specific person (ID) has Time 1

b) Number of Networkpartners (who have no NA in the outcome at this measurement) a specific person (ID) at Time 2

c) Number of Networkpartners (who have no NA in the outcome at this measurement) a specific person (ID) at Time 3

So I would like to create a dataset like this:

```
ID  NP  Time Outcome  NP.T1  NP.T2  NP.T3
1   11  1    4        2      2      1
1   11  2    3        2      2      1
1   11  3    NA       2      2      1
1   12  1    2        2      2      1
1   12  2    3        2      2      1
1   12  3    3        2      2      1
2   21  1    2        2      1      1
2   21  2    NA       2      1      1
2   21  3    NA       2      1      1
2   22  1    4        2      1      1
2   22  2    4        2      1      1
2   22  3    4        2      1      1
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: its very difficult to understand your request. Can you please format your description a bit so it makes more sense.

Comment: edited the description of the 3 variables i would like to create again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create one variable rather than three. I am using `ddply` from plyr package for 
that.

```
mydata<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), NP = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 22L), Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), Outcome = c(4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 
4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "NP", "Time", "Outcome"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))


    library(plyr)
    mydata1<-ddply(mydata,.(ID,Time),transform, NP.T=length(Outcome[which(Outcome !="NA")]))
>mydata1
   ID NP Time Outcome NP.T
1   1 11    1       4    2
2   1 12    1       2    2
3   1 11    2       3    2
4   1 12    2       3    2
5   1 11    3      NA    1
6   1 12    3       3    1
7   2 21    1       2    2
8   2 22    1       4    2
9   2 21    2      NA    1
10  2 22    2       4    1
11  2 21    3      NA    1
12  2 22    3       4    1
```

**Updated**: You can also use `interaction` to create the unique variable that combines ID and Time (comb)

```
mydata1<-ddply(mydata,.(ID,Time),transform, NP.T=length(Outcome[which(Outcome !="NA")]),comb=interaction(ID,Time))
```

Comment: Ok and how do i calculate the mean and sd of the number of networkpartners at each of the three measurements and the number of persons (ID) for each measurement? i would the also like to do an anova for repeated measures to answer the question if at least two of the three means for the number of networkpartners (NP) are different across the three measurements.

Comment: @ Metrics: I cant find the new variable in my dataset. could u please help me again?

Comment: I was able to do that with the above code; you should be able to do that too!

Comment: ok, maybe i just takes a while, cause its more than 100,000 rows. Could that be the case?

Comment: yeah `ddply` takes some time with large number of rows

Comment: kk, so i wait for it it an let you know if it has worked, later

Comment: [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 126221 rows ] that was what i was getting, so you would say that it just will take a while, right?

Comment: how many rows are in the table?You can't print all the rows in the console (the warning occurs because of that). Just use `write.csv(mydata2,file="mydata1.csv")` and see the csv file for all rows (FYI: mydata1 is the output)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really didn't work. There is no new collumn in my data :-(

Comment: 'data.frame': 126384 obs. of  60 variables

Comment: no i worked with my real dataset. the only thing i get is an output with thousands of rows ommitted, but the dataset doesn't channge. the is no new variable in it.

Comment: You need to first work with the sample data that you gave here in the question and then I can help if it is still not working

Comment: Thank u so much, it suddenly works now. I don't know what i did wrong, but now it works!!!!! thank you a lot