# Mean, SD, ANOVA for repeated measures longitudinal

Tags: r, mean, anova, standard-deviation

Three Measurements (Time) are nested in Networkpartners (NP) which are nested in Persons (ID). The variable NP.T (created according to the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027823/creating-a-new-columns-from-a-data-frame)) indicates the number of Networkpartners (with no missing value on the Outcome) a specific person (ID) has on a specific measurement (1 to 3).

This is an example for my dataset, the real one has thousands of rows though.

```
   ID NP   Time Outcome  NP.T
1   1 11    1       4    2
2   1 12    1       2    2
3   1 11    2       3    2
4   1 12    2       3    2
5   1 11    3      NA    1
6   1 12    3       3    1
7   2 21    1       2    2
8   2 22    1       4    2
9   2 21    2      NA    1
10  2 22    2       4    1
11  2 21    3      NA    1
12  2 22    3       4    1
```

I want to calculate the following things and donot know how to do this properly:

a) Mean, SD for the number of networkpartners at each measurement (NP.T).

Also I'm interested in the number of Persons (IDs) that named at least one Networkpartner at each measurement.

T1 -> 2 IDs named at least one Networkpartner

T2 -> 2 IDs named at least one NP

T3 -> 2 IDs named at least one NP

It may sound trivial in this example, but it's not in my sample. for the computation of the means, sds ect. for each time i want to take into account only those IDs who actually named at least one networkpartner at that specific time. IDs who didn't name any NP at that specific time shouldn't be a part of the descriptive statistics for that time point.
**For clarification: If there is an NA on the output-variable it means, that that NP hadn't been named by it's ID at that timepoint.**

b) reapeated measures ANOVA to find out if the mean number of networkpartners changes over the time

some Expected Results:

Mean.T1 = 2 <- as both IDs had named two NPs at T1

Mean.T2 = 1.5 <- as one ID had named two and the other one NP at T2

Mean.T3 = 1 <- as both IDs had named one NP at T3

n.T1 = 2

n.T2 = 2

n.T3 = 2

**The problem is, that in the real dataset all persons named different amounts of Networkpartners, so i don't know how to calculate the descriptive statistics in this case.**

Comment: do you want the mean of NP.T or NP?It's not clearer to me!If possible, please post the expected output for the given sample in your question.

Comment: there was a mistake in the expected results, i've corrected it now

Comment: You want `tapply`, `aggregate` and/or `by`.

Comment: What have you tried? Furthermore, to me it is unclear why you consider the 'The problem is...' a problem.

Comment: I just don't get it right. mean(NT.T,na.rm=T) doesn't seems to be right

Comment: No, at least not for your example data set where there is no variable called NT.T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part A(1 & 2)**

```
library(plyr)
mydata3<-ddply(mydata1,.(Time),summarize,mean=mean(NP.T),sd=sd(NP.T),nobs=length(unique(ID)))


 > mydata3
  Time mean        sd nobs
1    1  2.0 0.0000000    2
2    2  1.5 0.5773503    2
3    3  1.0 0.0000000    2
```

**Part B:**

> myaov <- aov(mean ~ Time, data=mydata3)

```
> myaov

    Call:
       aov(formula = mean ~ Time, data = mydata3)

    Terms:
                    Time Residuals
    Sum of Squares   0.5       0.0
    Deg. of Freedom    1         1

    Residual standard error: 1.17148e-16 
    Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

**Uodated:** For the error `Error in is.list(by) : 'by' is missing`, please check [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/850-ddply-misbehaving-in-rstudio-and-only-in-rstudio) for details. As mentioned in the website, this problem is not a problem of RStudio, but a problem of the Hmisc library masking the function `summarize` from the package 'plyr'.

So, you need to add `library(Hmisc)`in the earlier code.

```
library(plyr)
library(Hmisc)
    mydata3<-ddply(mydata1,.(Time),summarize,mean=mean(NP.T),sd=sd(NP.T),nobs=length(unique(ID)))
```

Comment: Please explain what does these mean: n.T1 = 2, n.T2 = 2 n.T3 = 2

Comment: n.T1 = 2 -> two IDs named at least 1 NP at T1 each and were therefore taken into account for the calculation of the descriptive statistics

Comment: Are you looking for the one that I just updated?

Comment: mydata3<-ddply(mydata1,.(Time),summarize,mean=mean(NP.T),sd=sd(NP.T),nobs=sum(NP.T)) doesnt work, there is an error:

Fehler in is.list(by) : 'by' fehlt

Comment: In my code, I don't have `nobs=sum(NP‌​.T))`. Where did you get that?

Comment: fehler means mistake.

Comment: mydata3<-ddply(mydata1,.(Time),summarize,mean=mean(NP.T),sd=sd(NP.T),nobs=length(unique(ID))) if i use this, 'by' still seems to be missing

Comment: its failure not Fehler; did you run this in this sample data or real data? and did you name your previous output as mydata1 and did you have Time variable in real data or time variable in real data (check the lower case/upper case of the variable)?

Comment: ok, the commando works now. but the problem is, that the number of observations is the  same for all three observations. the problem is, that some of the persons (ID) have droped out of the study or didn't took part at some measurements (you can recognize those persons by the value "0" at NP.T. and those drop-outs shall not be taken into account for the calculation of the means.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have 0 value for NP.T and you said n will be 2 for all values of T. So,you need to be more clear on your question. FYI: your question is already put on hold...

Comment: ok, i thought it would be to difficult to create an example with all cases, that could possibly happen. so i will post it more accurate later then. thank u for your help

Comment: Not a problem; if this answer is okay for the problem you posted (other than additional problems in comments) you should check the answer as accepted