# Creating a complicated new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a dataset which is in longformat in which Measurements (Time) are nested in Networkpartners (NP) which are nested in Persons (ID), here is an example of what it looks like (the real dataset has over thousands of rows):

```
ID  NP  Time Outcome1 Outcome2
1   11  1    4        NA
1   11  2    3        4
1   11  3    NA       NA
1   12  1    2        3
1   12  2    3        1
1   12  3    3        2
2   21  1    2        4
2   21  2    NA       NA
2   21  3    NA       NA
2   22  1    4        NA
2   22  2    4        3
2   22  3    NA       4
```

Now I would like to create the following new variable "NP.T":

The Number of Networkpartners (who have no NA in outcome1 AND outcome2 at this measurement) a specific person (ID) at a specific time. In other words: I want to count the NPs who have one or none NAs at the two outcome-variables. And I do not want to count those NPs who have NAs in BOTH outcome-variables.

So I would like to create a dataset like this:

```
ID  NP  Time Outcome1 Outcome2 NP.T
1   11  1    4        NA       2
1   11  2    3        4        2
1   11  3    NA       NA       1
1   12  1    2        3        2
1   12  2    3        1        2
1   12  3    3        2        1
2   21  1    2        4        2
2   21  2    NA       NA       1
2   21  3    NA       NA       1
2   22  1    4        NA       2
2   22  2    4        3        1
2   22  3    NA       4        1
```

I have the solution as provided in the earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027823/creating-a-new-columns-from-a-data-frame) on how to create a variable that counts the number of Networkpartners (who have no NA in ONE of the two outcomes) a specific person (ID) at a specific time:

```
library(plyr)
mydata1<-ddply(mydata,.(ID,Time),transform, NP.T=length(Outcome[which(Outcome !   ="NA")]))
```

Now, I'd be very thankful if somebody could help me to find an answer on my specific problem!

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting your `NP.T` variable...shouldn't the first value be 1?

Comment: @Thomas, I posted exactly the same comment. I realised (I think, correctly) that he doesn't want to count when *both* are NA. It's not worded properly and he/she doesn't seem to respond quickly. Well..

Comment: similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027823/creating-a-new-columns-from-a-data-frame) by the same user

Comment: @user2647568: I am not sure whether this is different from what you asked earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027823/creating-a-new-columns-from-a-data-frame), but it looks you are seeking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Hey, I want to count those NPs that have at least one value in the two outcomes. In other words: i do not want to count those NPs who have NAs in both outcome-variables, but i want to count those NPs who have one or none NA in the outcome-variables

Comment: So you have now two outcomes unlike one outcome in earlier question, but I think that can be easily handled using the the same approach

Comment: I am really sorry, but the problem is that it is not easy for me. I appreciate your help, Metrics, but I really can not translate your solution to this problem without help. Which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I must misunderstand the question because I'm not sure how you're getting the expected outcome vector. If you want the number of NP's for each ID/time combination that have no `NA` values for either outcome, try the following.

```
# data:
mydf <- read.table(text="ID  NP  Time Outcome1 Outcome2
1   11  1    4        NA
1   11  2    3        4
1   11  3    NA       NA
1   12  1    2        3
1   12  2    3        1
1   12  3    3        2
2   21  1    2        4
2   21  2    NA       NA
2   21  3    NA       NA
2   22  1    4        NA
2   22  2    4        3
2   22  3    NA       4",header=TRUE)

# ave:
mydf$NP.T <- with(mydf, ave(NP*as.numeric(rowSums(is.na(cbind(Outcome1,Outcome2)))==0),
                            list(ID,Time),
                            FUN=function(x) sum(unique(x)>0)))
#[1] 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

If Arun's comment is correct, then this is what you want:

```
mydf$NP.T <- with(mydf, ave(NP*as.numeric(rowSums(is.na(cbind(Outcome1,Outcome2)))<2),
                            list(ID,Time),
                            FUN=function(x) sum(unique(x)>0)))
#[1] 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: Hey, I want to count those NPs that have at least one value in the two outcomes. In other words: i do not want to count those NPs who have NAs in both outcome-variables, but i want to count those NPs who have one or none NA in the outcome-variables.

Comment: @user2647568 Well, I've given you two answers. If one of them works for you, let me know.

Comment: the second one could be working but i don't know how to get this new variable into my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using plyr package which is similar to what I posted [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027823/creating-a-new-columns-from-a-data-frame).

```
mydata<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), NP = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 22L), Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), Outcome1 = c(4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 
4L, 4L, NA), Outcome2 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "NP", "Time", "Outcome1", "Outcome2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
> mydata
   ID NP Time Outcome1 Outcome2
1   1 11    1        4       NA
2   1 11    2        3        4
3   1 11    3       NA       NA
4   1 12    1        2        3
5   1 12    2        3        1
6   1 12    3        3        2
7   2 21    1        2        4
8   2 21    2       NA       NA
9   2 21    3       NA       NA
10  2 22    1        4       NA
11  2 22    2        4        3
12  2 22    3       NA        4

mydata1<-ddply(mydata,.(ID,Time),transform,NP.T=length(which(!(Outcome1 =="NA" & Outcome2 =="NA"))))
> mydata1
   ID NP Time Outcome1 Outcome2 NP.T
1   1 11    1        4       NA    2
2   1 12    1        2        3    2
3   1 11    2        3        4    2
4   1 12    2        3        1    2
5   1 11    3       NA       NA    1
6   1 12    3        3        2    1
7   2 21    1        2        4    2
8   2 22    1        4       NA    2
9   2 21    2       NA       NA    1
10  2 22    2        4        3    1
11  2 21    3       NA       NA    1
12  2 22    3       NA        4    1
```